# Trying to get value from select form with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

What I am trying to do is get the selected value from the measurement form to pass using `MeasurementID: $('#measurement').find(":selected").val()` instead of using `php`, but it does not seem to work. I have also tried `$('select[name=measurement]').val()` and `$('#measurement option:selected').val()`

```
  <div>

            <?php
            require 'getMeasurementTypesByUser.php';
            $option1 = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : false;
            if ($option1) {
                $res = getMeasurementTypesByUser($_GET['user']);

                echo '<form method="post" action=""><select id="measurement" name="measurement" onchange="this.form.submit();">';
                echo '<option value="">Select Measurement</option>';
                foreach ($res as $row) {
                    if ($row['MeasurementID'] != 1 && $row['MeasurementID'] != 2) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['MeasurementID'] . '">' . $row['MeasurementName'] . '</option>';
                    }else if($row['MeasurementID']== 1 ){
                        echo '<option value="1">Pressure</option>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</select></form>';
                $UserID = htmlentities($_GET['user'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            }
            $option = isset($_POST['measurement']) ? $_POST['measurement'] : false;
            if ($option) {
                $MeasurementID = htmlentities($_POST['measurement'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
                if($MeasurementID==1){
                    $MeasurementID2=2;
                }
            }
            echo '<form method="get" action=""><select id="user" name="user" onchange="this.form.submit();">';
            echo '<option value="">Select User ID</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form>';
            ?>

        </div>
        <!-- javascript -->
        <script src="libs/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Kostas/measurementData.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {UserID: <?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>, MeasurementID: $('#measurement').find(":selected").val()}, //here
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
//goes on
```

Comment: don't mix js and php - it's bad practice

Comment: That's why I am trying to avoid it, and I want to use this to start removing the php from inside js, but it doesnt work. If I find how to pass the value using JS I will remove the other php parts

Comment: Using JQuery if you want to get the dropdown selected value, try
$("#measurement).val();

Comment: @RahulDasgupta no it didn't work either

Comment: @Constantine, in your code if I am not wrong I am seeing you are simply populating the dropdown, along with this you also need to make an option selected. Once you make the option selected, it should work

Comment: @RahulDasgupta well I made the Pressure option selected and it works, though only for that option, everytime i am  trying to select something else in the form it just resets to the Pressure option. Should i remove the <form> ?

Comment: @Constantine see my answer - should hopefully work :D

Comment: @Constantine , you have to use setTimeout(function(){this.form.submit()},500) onChange event .

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I am trying to figure out how to implement it on my code, give me a minute

Comment: @Constantine If I have understood properly you want to call some ajax for the dropdown option you have selected. In that case you need to call the function onChange event of the dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how I'd do it:

html:

```
<select data-user="<?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>" id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.mySubmitBtn').on('click', function()
        {
            var selected = $('#mySelect').val(),
                userId   = $('#mySelect').data('user');

            $.ajax({
                data:    {value: selected, user: userId},
                url:     'myScript.php',
                type:    'post',
                success: function(res) {console.log(res)},
                error:   function(res) {console.log(res)}
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

what this does is, assign user id to the select as a data value. This means we can use `.data` to retrive data elements - syntax is: `.data('attribute')` - so that would get data-attribute.

it then gets selected value on click, the issue with doing ajax straight away, is that it is getting the selected value, but on document load, not on any update. That's why it shows the old value.

It then passes it all to a script to do whatever with.

NOTE: THIS CODE IS NOT LIKE FOR LIKE FOR YOURS SO DON'T JUST COPY AND PASTE ;)

### update 1

An example (js) more tailored for OP

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#mySelect').on('change', function()
        {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val(),
                userId   = $(this).data('user');

            $.ajax({
                data:    {value: selected, user: userId},
                url:     'myScript.php',
                type:    'post',
                success: function(res) {console.log(res)},
                error:   function(res) {console.log(res)}
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: from what i have figured out so far, i have to change it to on('change', instead of click but i can't figure out what to  change on $('.mySubmitBtn') cause i don't have a submit button

Comment: @Constantine - it depends, in my example, I submit forms with a button instead of `input type="submit"` - I'll update my answer to suit you :)

Comment: Still not working, check my select, do you think the fact that it has a form or there is a  onchange="this.form.submit(); causes problems?

Comment: @Constantine ah didn't see the inline JS! Never do inline js or inline css either hahaha remove and it should work

Comment: still didn't work, i am probably doing some stupid mistake, I pasted the code, can you check it up? https://paste.ofcode.org/YmNiEZ6hAaPu2iEDzqGvsJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150169/discussion-between-constantine-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).

Answer (score 0):

You may try below

you have to add the setTimeout .

```
<select id="user" name="user" onchange="fun_submit(this)" ></select>

fun_submit(obj){
   setTimeout(function(){obj.form.submit();},500);

}
```

Then you can use below method for get the value of selected option.

```
var value = $('select#measurement option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="options" id="options">
    <option value="one">Option 1</option>
    <option value="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Js code to get the value of the selected option.

```
$('#options').val();
```

Comment: @Constantine whats the html output after you run the php? Might be a problem with generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#measurement').val()
```

The `.val()` on the select element itself is enough in recent jquery versions.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Demo:

```js
function displayVals() {
  var singleValues = $( "#single" ).val();
  var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val() || [];
  
  // When using jQuery 3:
  // var multipleValues = $( "#multiple" ).val();
  $( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues +
    " <b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join( ", " ) );
}
 
$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="single">
  <option>Single</option>
  <option>Single2</option>
</select>
 
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
  <option>Multiple2</option>
  <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```

Comment: in an option <option value="1">Some</option> wont that get the "Some" text instead of 1?

Comment: @Constantine Read the question wrong. Updated, answer.